# open all links in the browser

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need all links open in a new browser window and not in the application. This particularly do know but it happens that I am occupying a google maps, it has a link to "Terms and Conditions" and click on, opens into ionic my application and can not pass it. Anyone have any idea if there is a directive or service that does this?

I'm working with ionic framework.

Comment: i mean, typically this is done with the attribute: `target="_blank"`, but you can't control the google map iframe's link unless the google map api allows it..

Comment: Ah understand, I imagined I could be something. Well I give as an answer then, I guess I could put a div or something to cover that link and not allow it to click. Leave it in response to leave no question unanswered. Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Assume you are looking for this tutorial. It will stop all your  tag and open those links in a InAppBrowser.

```
window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_system’);   Loads in the system browser
window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_blank’);    Loads in the InAppBrowser    
window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_blank’, ‘location=no’); Loads in the InAppBrowser with no location bar
window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_self’); Loads in the Cordova web view
```

Tutorial [Here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/)

Comment: If he assumed that it was so, just wanted to handle any type of link and no I declare, but I was clear that I can not do that. Thanks for your answer!